# Correct way to serialise and deserialise data?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an array of class data which I'm serialising into a byte array then pushing it into a database.  This program runs on a scheduled basis during the night.  On the other end I have another program which pulls this data out of the database, processes it into a report - or at least that's the plan.
The class is incased in 2 namespaces, first the the application name, the second is just something to hold my structures. Eg below.

```
namespace FibreTrend
{
    namespace Structures
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class Trend
        {
            public Trend(DateTime date, string ref, int port)
            {
                Date = date;
                Reference = ref;
                PortNo = port;
            }

            public DateTime Date;
            public string Reference;
            public int PortNo;
        }
    }
}


{
    // Function to take the trendData list, convert it to a byte array
    // List<Structures.Trend> trendData;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         bf.Serialize(mStream, trendData.ToArray());
         byte[] b = mStream.ToArray();
         // code that pushes the array into the database...
    }
}
```

I have a completely separate application which reads in the data from the database as the byte array.  I then go to converting it from the bytes back to my data class.

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
    mStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Structures.Trend[] obj = (Structures.Trend[])binaryFormat.Deserialize(mStream);
}
```

And here is my error.  Its telling me it wants the FibreTrend binary to deserialize the data.  Why??  My Trend class is the same size, same data layout, its an exact copy and paste from my other project.  Why is it insisting on needing my other binary file in companion. When I do put the binary with it then deserialise it into an object it comes put as a FibreTrend.Structures.Trend[]. I'm obviously not going to include the other binary file with it, I'm also not going to double handle the data converting it to a Report.Structures.Trend[].  Its just a stream of 1s and 0s, why can't I just push it into any class that I deem I want, isn't that the purpose of the cast to tell the compiler how I want the data ordered and structured?

Comment: Because you’re using a serializer that makes sure the data is put into the exact same type as it was before. You’re free to use other serialization methods, make a shared data assembly, or use any other mechanism to share data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary Serialized data stream contains a header with type information in it. You can refer to the Binary Format Data structure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nrbf/75b9fe09-be15-475f-85b8-ae7b7558cfe5). That's why you are getting that exception about missing assembly.

One way to solve your issue is by implementing a `SerializationBinder` that overrides the type to be deserialized into at runtime and set `Binder` property on `BinaryFormatter`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) is a very good example.

A preferred solution would be to use alternative serialization formats such as XML, JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the input Sthotakura.  I ended up going the Binder route, its good information to know.  I might work with xml or json for future instances.  Thanks.